# Setting Spotify as Default Music Player for Windows 7

Tags: default-settings, spotify

I want to make spotify as my default music player.

I have the music button in my keyboard and I want to open spotify whenever I pressed this music button, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is useful if you have the music button in your keyboard, one tap then you can spotify.

For windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10:

Based on [community.spotify.com](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Set-Spotify-as-default-media-player/td-p/46763/page/2) by going to "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations" and selecting .cda then click change program then select Spotify and pressing ok will solve the problem.

**Note:**

If it didn't work choose .mpa then select spotify as the default program will solve the problem.

Update:

If it still didn't work then choose .mp3 and .mp4 then select spotify as the default program.

[image]